# How does a connection act on a one form?

Tags: manifolds, connections

It is well discussed how a connection acts on a vector with parallel transport. For example, have a look at 17:29 of [this video](https://youtu.be/cEEahoUUGyc?t=1049) by Eigen -Chris. However, I have never seen a visualization of the covariant derivative acts on one forms. Could a geometrical idea of how we are taking a derivative of a one form be given?